# Passing value to input from HREF

Tags: jquery

I am developing a web site that uses [FooTable](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable#readme) to display a product list; I have included the FooTable plugins for sorting and filtering table data, too.

What I'm looking to do is include a list of links in my site navigation that forces filtering of the FooTable by pre-populating the input box, e.g., the link:

```
http://www.mysite.com/products.html?search=queryterm
```

would take visitors to the products.html page and already show "queryterm" in the input box and filter the table accordingly. As I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript both, I haven't been able to sort out how to do this without breaking the existing functionality of [footable.filter.js](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable/blob/master/js/footable.filter.js).

The queryterm would consist of any of the following: single terms, phrases, numbers and fractions (e.g., 1/16).